# How to delete a child of a many-to-one relationship without deleting the parent too?

Tags: java, many-to-many, associations

I'm trying to realize reservations of a rooms by a user.
So a user can make a reservation of a room, which then is saved as an new (child?) object in the database.

**public class User**

```
@Entity
public class User implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    private String lastname;
    private String firstname;
}
```

**public class Room**

```
@Entity
public class Room implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    private String roomDescription;
}
```

**public class Reservation**

```
@Entity
public class Reservation implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    @ManyToOne (cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private User user;

    @ManyToOne (cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Room room;

    public Reservation() {

    }

    public Reservation(Room room, User, user) {
        super();
        this.room= room;
        this.user= user;
    }
}
```

**The issue:**
I can initialize/save reservations with a user and a room. 
But when I delete a reservation, it deletes the (whole objects) of the user and room too (in the database).

I tried to add the `orphanRemoval = false` or `orphanRemoval = true` for the `@ManyToOne` in the `class Reservation` but this doesn't work.

How can I fix that it just deletes the reservation but not the user and room out of the database? Thanks!

Comment: Remove this cascade=ALL on your two ManyToOne. That's precisely what tells JPA: when I delete a reservation, also do the deletion on the linked user and the linked room. You don't want that. You can also remove fetch=EAGER, since that's the default value for toOne annotations.